# Ruby geocoder on Heroku yields private IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ip, rails-geocoder

Ruby Geocoder (http://rubygeocoder.com/) works fine for getting the latitude and longitude of a known address. Now I am trying to use it to look up a Country code by IP Address so that a new user won't have to select their country.

```
if @person.country.blank?
    ip_loc = Geocoder.search(my_ip_address)
    if ip_loc.present?
       @person.country = ip_loc[0].data['country_code']
    end
end
```

To get their IP address to feed Geocoder, I am using socket:

```
 def my_ip_address
    require 'socket'
    list=Socket.ip_address_list
    ip = list.detect{|intf| intf.ipv4_private?}
    ip.ip_address if ip
 end
```

Since IP lookup won't work for a development machine (IP address is always a private, internal number) I am trying to test this on Heroku.

When this runs on Heroku, however, I am still getting back a private IP address 172.19.75.142 which cannot be looked up with Geocoder.

Can someone steer me in a productive direction for getting Country from IP that will work on Heroku?

Comment: Just to be clear... you want the the IP address (and with that the country) for the server running the application?  Not the user visiting the site?

Comment: I want the IP address of the user who is accessing the server. It is their country I am trying to determine.

Comment: Then like Joel Brewer mentions below, you want request.remote_ip.  Note that if you're developing locally this will still be an internal IP so you should have a fall back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the ip address of the user/client with [`request.remote_ip`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Request/remote_ip). You should then be able to feed this value into Geocoder.

Note that `request` will only be available in your controllers.

Comment: For local development, you can add this conditional check to skip the lookup.  If this is true, don't bother as it's a private IP.  `['127.0.0.0/8', '10.0.0.0/8', '172.16.0.0/12', '192.168.0.0/16', '192.168.10.0/8'].none?{|block| IPAddr.new(block) === request.remote_ip}`

Comment: Thanks to both for the helpful info!

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom It took me a bit to realize that what you gave is meant for an if statement.  In the else block we should use the `request.remote_ip`